# Serilog EventId property type variance between Serilog.Context.LogContext and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: serilog

I am trying to use the `EventId` property in the output template for a console sink. When I add the event id using `Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty`, it appears in the context as a `Serilog.Events.ScalarValue`. When I add the event id using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.LogInformation` overload that accepts an event id as the first parameter, it appears in the context as a `Serilog.Events.StructureValue`.

The following MRE produces the behavior:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Context;

internal class Program
{
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger;

    public Program(ILogger<Program> logger) => this.logger = logger;

    static void Main()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(
                outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff}] [{Level}] [{EventId}] {Message:l}{NewLine}{Exception}")
            .WriteTo.EventLog(
                nameof(SerilogRepro),
                manageEventSource: true)
            .CreateLogger();

        var servicesProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<Program>()
            .AddLogging(logging => logging.AddSerilog())
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        var program = servicesProvider.GetRequiredService<Program>();
        program.Run();

        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("EventId", 42))
        {
            Log.Information("EventId added using Serilog.Context.LogContext.");
        }

        this.logger.LogInformation(52, "EventId added using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.");
    }
}
```

The resulting console output is as follows:

```
[2022-08-21 16:19:38.8027] [Information] [42] EventId added using Serilog.Context.LogContext.
[2022-08-21 16:19:38.9256] [Information] [{ Id: 52 }] EventId added using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.
```

Since the `EventId` is a structure and not a scalar value when using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, it is rendered incorrectly.

In my actual configuration, I use a custom event id provider with the event log sink that distinguishes the two types and applies the correct value. However, the console sink obviously does not facilitate this.

I need to be able to support calls to both libraries, what is the optimal approach for this case?

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a better solution, I have addressed the issue using an expression template and the `Serilog.Expressions` package.

```csharp
const string consoleTemplate =
    "[{@t:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}] " +
    "[{@l}] " +
    "[{Coalesce(EventId.Id, EventId)}] " +
    "{@m:l}\n" +
    "{@x}";

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console(
        new ExpressionTemplate(consoleTemplate))
    .WriteTo.EventLog(
        nameof(SerilogRepro),
        manageEventSource: true)
    .CreateLogger();
```